# how to get data from ESP8266 WiFi AccessPoint withouit refresh HTML page

Tags: javascript, wifi, refresh

Currently I am getting data from a hardware device(charge/load controller) over WiFi, it has an ESP8266 configured as an AccessPoint.
The WiFi is setup to ignore all request from computer, just send its data once per second.
The data is a single string representing about 20 JavaScript Variables...
var xx1="text1";
var xx2="text2"; etc...

I get the data by refreshing the HTML5 page, process with JavaScript & logging to localStorage.
It all works well except I can only refresh about 3 second interval minimum for reliable consistent data-logging. The browser (FireFox) takes a while to complete refresh.

Q. Is there a way I can get every 'data send' using JavaScript without page refresh, this way I can log just the periodic strings I choose from 1 second to xxx second.
I suspect I might need to install some library component to access with my JavaScript ?, i would need to embed this into my HTML file if possible or have it reside in the same folder.

I have been learning JS for about 2 weeks now, getting most from examples & my mistakes.

Comment: `Is there a way I can get every 'data send' using JavaScript without page refresh` - it depends on the code running in the ESP9266

Comment: default AT firmware provided by Espressif